# How would one solve the staircase problem recursively with a variable number of steps?

Tags: algorithm

The problem of determining the n amount of ways to climb a staircase given you can take 1 or 2 steps is well known with the Fibonacci sequencing solution being very clear. However how exactly could one solve this recursively if you also assume that you can take a variable M amount of steps?

I tried to make a quick mockup of this algorithm in typescript with

```
function counter(n: number, h: number){
  console.log(`counter(n=${n},h=${h})`);
  let sum = 0
  if(h<1) return 0;
  sum = 1
  if (n>h) {
    n = h;
  }
  if (n==h) {
    sum = Math.pow(2, h-1)
    console.log(`return sum=${sum}, pow(2,${h-1}) `)
    return sum
  }
  for (let c = 1; c <= h; c++) {
    console.log(`c=${c}`)
    sum += counter(n, h-c);
    console.log(`sum=${sum}`)
  }
  console.log(`return sum=${sum}`)
  return sum;
}

let result = counter (2, 4);
console.log(`result=${result}`)
```

but unfortunately this doesn't seem to work for most cases where the height is not equal to the number of steps one could take.

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be solved with recursive DP.

```
vector<vector<int>> dp2;            //[stair count][number of jumps]

int stair(int c, int p) {
    int& ret = dp2[c][p];
    if (ret != -1) return ret;      //If you've already done same search, return saved result
    if (c == n) {                   //If you hit the last stair, return 1
        return ret = 1;
    }
    int s1 = 0, s2 = 0;
    if (p < m) {                    //If you can do more jumps, make recursive call
        s1 = stair(c + 1, p + 1);
        if (c + 2 <= n) {           //+2 stairs can jump over the last stair. That shouldn't happen.
            s2 = stair(c + 2, p + 1);           
        }
    }
    return ret = s1 + s2;           //Final result will be addition of +1 stair methods and +2 methods
}

int main()
{
    ios::sync_with_stdio(0); cin.tie(0); cout.tie(0);
    cin >> n >> m; dp2 = vector<vector<int>>(n + 1, vector<int>(m + 1, -1));
    for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
        dp2[n][i] = 1;              //All last stair method count should be 1, because there is no more after.
    }
    cout << stair(0, 0) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Example IO 1

```
5 5
8
// 1 1 1 1 1
// 1 1 1 2
// 1 1 2 1
// 1 2 1 1
// 2 1 1 1
// 1 2 2
// 2 1 2
// 2 2 1
```

Example IO 2

```
5 4
7
// 1 1 1 2
// 1 1 2 1
// 1 2 1 1
// 2 1 1 1
// 1 2 2
// 2 1 2
// 2 2 1
```

Example IO 3

```
5 3
3
// 1 2 2
// 2 1 2
// 2 2 1
```